# How to consume WebService returned DataTable from ASP.net with PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, datatable

I want to know, how to properly "consume" **DataTable** which is returned in ASP.net WebService method.

I work on this examples:

**ASP.net WEBSERVICE:**

```
[WebMethod]
public DataTable searchDatabase(string search)
{

    SqlConnection conn = null;
    SqlDataReader rdr = null;
    conn = new
                    SqlConnection("Data Source=ASUSX301A\\MSSQLINSTANCE;Initial Catalog=db_sp_vaje;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
    conn.Open();

    // 1.  create a command object identifying
    //     the stored procedure
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "dbo.sp_iskanje", conn); //here is my stored procedure which works 100%

    // 2. set the command object so it knows
    //    to execute a stored procedure
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // 3. add parameter to command, which
    //    will be passed to the stored procedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add(
        new SqlParameter("@myInput", search));

    // execute the command
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.TableName = "oglasi";
    dt.WriteXml(@"path", true);
    da.Fill(dt);

    // iterate through results, printing each to console


    return dt; 
}
```

If I call this webservice also in ASP.net works fine & I get results from datatable with loop.

**Now how can I get this datatable from webservice that I can show/echo in PHP?**

So far I have in my PHP file this: (BTW: if I call default HelloWorld() webservice method from ASP.net in PHP works great)

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:10994/WebService.asmx?WSDL");
$params->Param1 = "car"; //this is search variable
$result = $client->searchDatabase($params)->searchDatabaseResult;

print_r ($result);
```

And result is:
[image: php error]

Comment: Hi! it is a long time but I'm working in a project like you described above. My problem is how to manipulate columns and rows of a DataTable returned. I can call the function successfuly but the DataTable's result is together as one string. Could you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
$params->search = "car"; //this is search variable
```

It's working nice for me, but I don't know how to work with rows and columns :-(

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this and works fine.

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/WebService.asmx?WSDL");
$result = $client->__soapCall("functionName", array($SoapCallParameters));

var_dump($result->functionNameResult);
```